# How to get same TOC for tex4ht as with PDF?

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht

TOC in tex4ht still confuses me to this day.  Does one still need to use

```
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{section,subsection,etc...}
```

or can tex4ht use the standard latex setting used for PDF, which is

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % for main TOC (change number as needed)
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents
```

I am asking because below it shows one must use the `\Configure` command. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
%
\title{Notes on something important}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % for main TOC to go all way to \paragraph
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents
%
\section{Very important section}
\subsection{Very important subsection}
\subsubsection{Very important subsubsection}
Hence we see that
\paragraph{some results}
Therefore we see it is proven.
\end{document}
```

Compile to pdf using `lualatex` gives

[image]

So TOC shows the `\paragraph`, but using same code, compiled to html using

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug  main.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

gives

[image]

It does not show `\paragraph`.  If I modify the latex part for toc to do this

```
\ifdefined\HCode
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\else
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % for main TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents
\fi
```

Now HTML gives

[image]

So now `paragraph` shows in TOC but with no number. But finally If I change the latex to

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % for main TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\ifdefined\HCode
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\else
\tableofcontents
\fi
```

Now the HTML is correct

[image]

So my question is: It is possible to have the above output directly just using

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % for main TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents
```

Without having to add

```
\ifdefined\HCode
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\else...\fi
```

Since it seems to me the information for tex4ht is already there, so why does one have to add the `\Configure` command. It will simplify the Latex.

What is the correct way to set the TOC in tex4ht to be the same as the PDF? Does one need to always have the `\Configure` there?

TL 2023

**Update July 27, 2023**

Unfortunately the solution given does not work when asking to split the document, which is 90% of the cases I have. i.e. moving the commands `\setcounter{tocdepth}` and `\setcounter{secnumdepth}` works in tex4ht only if one does not ask to split the document. Otherwise the whole TOC no longer shows up!  Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % for main TOC, show part and chapter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\title{my book}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\part{first part}
\chapter{first chapter in part 1}
things here

\part{second  part}
\chapter{first  chapter in part 2}
more things here
\end{document}
```

And now compiling using

```
make4ht -ulm default -a warning  main.tex 'mathjax,htm,2'
```

And looking at the HTML, there is no TOC at all showing. Nothing. Just blank space.  But compiling using

```
make4ht -ulm default -a warning  main.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

The correct TOC now shows in the HTML.

The workaround is to go back to using `\Configure` for text4ht, like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\title{my book}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\ifdefined\HCode 
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{part,chapter}
\else 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % for main TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents
\fi 

\part{first part}
\chapter{first chapter in part 1}
things here

\part{second  part}
\chapter{first  chapter in part 2}
more things here
\end{document}
```

And now compiling using same command, with any level of splitting, the TOC shows on the main page OK and never goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TOC handling is quite complex in TeX4ht.  If you don't use `\Configure{tableofcontents*}`, it will print section levels according to the value of `tocdepth` at the moment when `.4ht` files are loaded, which means at `\begin{document}`. So, if you move this definition to your document preamble, it should work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % for main TOC to go all way to \paragraph
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
%
\title{Notes on something important}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
%
\section{Very important section}
\subsection{Very important subsection}
\subsubsection{Very important subsubsection}
Hence we see that
\paragraph{some results}
Therefore we see it is proven.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea I needed to put `\setcounter` code in preamble for it to work. This will simplify my latex so I can get rid of all the `\Configure{tableofcontents*}..` code and just use the same one for pdf.

Comment: @Nasser I didn't know about it too, I was just experimenting :) Anyway, it makes more sense to have such declarations in the preamble.

Comment: After more testing, I found the above actually does not work. I had to go back to using `\Configure{tableofcontents*}`. I will post an example soon showing the problem. May be you could find a solution, but for now, using `\Configure{tableofcontents*}` is a workaround, which is what I was doing all the time. I was hoping I can remove this if not needed.

Comment: I just wanted to say, that using `\Configure{tableofcontents*}{...}` is not a big deal. So unless you want to find a fix for this, no need to spend your time on this. Since you mentioned that TOC handling on tex4ht is very complex code. so I am OK with keep using `\Configure{tableofcontents*}{...}` in addition to keeping the counter commands in preamble. Now TOC always shows up when using any split level.